# Create django query from string

Tags: python, django, parsing

I have a list of strings that come in a strange format like this:

```
OR(EQUAL(id,111),EQUAL(id,222)) 
AND(EQUAL(id,333),EQUAL(name,"John"))
```

I want to parse these strings and run them as a filter in Django like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

People.objects.filter(Q(id=111) | Q(id=222))
People.objects.filter(Q(id=333) & Q(name="John"))
```

Is there a parser that can help me with this? Or would I have to write one from scratch?

Comment: What can be helpful here is the fact that the strings seem to be valid Python syntax. You might implement the functions and do an `eval()` with a namespace limited to that functions. Only the names could be tricky.

Comment: Where are these strings being generated? Changing the format of the strings to something more easily parsed would be the ideal solution